# How to call onget method with parameters in .net core using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I tried to call this onget method in .net core using ajax call but this method hitting without parameters

```
 public void OnGet(string id,string refundReason ,int amount)
        {           
           
        }
```

I used these 2 ajax call but not passing parameter values

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions/Refund?id="+'20a63762-a6ab-4edb-852b-fd247e9dc247'+"&refundReason="+refundReason+"&amount="+amount,
    type: "GET",              
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
      debugger;
      
    },
});
```

this one alse tried not passing values to onget method. let me know what changes i've to do. Thanks

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions/,
        type: "GET",       
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: '20a63762-a6ab-4edb-852b-fd247e9dc247',
                               refundReason:'tt',
                               amount:"1"
                            }),
```

Comment: Hi, the first way should work with or without set `data`. How is your html code like? How do you invoke the ajax? If you invoke it by button click, be sure it is `type="button"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to call it with `$.get` and passing the values in the query string. GET calls do not accept body data.

```
$.get(`https://localhost:7197/Transactions/Refund?id=20a63762-a6ab-4edb-852b-fd247e9dc247&refundReason=${refundReason}&amount=${amount}`, response => {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should indicate how you want to get parameters from the client. Try using the `[FromQuery]`, `[FromBody]`, `[FromForm]` attributes on your parameters. You also need to specify your request method: `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, etc.

Second, in the code you posted, you send data from the body and also from the query string. GET request does not have a body in .NET so you should send from Query.

This should work:

```
[HttpGet]
public void OnGet([FromQuery]string id, string refundReason, int amount)
```

In the AJAX code, remove the `data` section, and please be sure you are giving the right URL parameter to the AJAX code.

It should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions?id=someid&refundReason=somevalue&someamount,
        type: "GET"
       })
```